su -l shell seems to close automatically when remote is WinSCP
I have a script invoked at ssh invocation (on Linux) to run some commands and then
login as a different user su -l <anotheruser> - all this works fine, when I use
any Linux based scp/ssh clients. But when I try with WinScp (with File Protocol SCP in options) it does not work!
On troubleshooting further, it seems like the shell invoked via su -l <anotheruser> is
somehow getting killed!
So, I see the following in WinScp log:
(EFatal) **Connection has been unexpectedly closed.** Server sent command exit status 1

But I am not able to figure out why the su login shell is getting killed only when
using WinScp! Any pointers to debug further?
--EDIT--
Last few lines from WinSCP log:
! 2024-07-27 00.23.13.824 su: must be run from a terminal
. 2024-07-27 00.23.13.824 Session sent command exit status 1
. 2024-07-27 00.23.13.824 Main session channel closed
. 2024-07-27 00.23.13.824 All channels closed
. 2024-07-27 00.23.13.824 Timeout waiting for network events
. 2024-07-27 00.23.13.824 Waiting for another 1 bytes
. 2024-07-27 00.23.13.824 Looking for incoming data
. 2024-07-27 00.23.13.824 Looking for network events
. 2024-07-27 00.23.13.824 Attempt to close connection due to fatal exception:
* 2024-07-27 00.23.13.824 **Connection has been unexpectedly closed.** Server sent command exit status 1.
. 2024-07-27 00.23.13.824 Closing connection.
. 2024-07-27 00.23.13.824 Selecting events 0 for socket 1932
* 2024-07-27 00.23.13.856 (EFatal) **Connection has been unexpectedly closed.** Server sent command exit status 1.
* 2024-07-27 00.23.13.856 Error skipping startup message. Your shell is probably incompatible with the application (BASH is recommended).

Does the line
! 2024-07-27 00.23.13.824 su: must be run from a terminal

Indicate an issue!?
My script is invoked via a NSS plugin (libnss-ato)
--EDIT 2--
After using a su version from util-linux which has a --pty option, winscp seems to get stuck! logs:
< 2024-08-02 15.00.55.772 tani1@sys7-vm81B$ echo "WinSCP: this is end-of-file:0"
. 2024-08-02 15.00.55.772 Read 31 bytes (18 pending)
< 2024-08-02 15.00.55.772 WinSCP: this is end-of-file:0
. 2024-08-02 15.00.55.772 Read 18 bytes (0 pending)
. 2024-08-02 15.00.55.772 Waiting for another 1 bytes
. 2024-08-02 15.00.55.772 Looking for incoming data
. 2024-08-02 15.00.55.772 Looking for network events
. 2024-08-02 15.01.12.135 Timeout waiting for network events
. 2024-08-02 15.01.12.135 Waiting for data timed out, asking user what to do.
. 2024-08-02 15.01.12.135 Asking user:
. 2024-08-02 15.01.12.135 **Host is not communicating for 15 seconds.
. 2024-08-02 15.01.12.135 
. 2024-08-02 15.01.12.135 Wait for another 15 seconds?** ()


What protocol are you using with WinSCP?

@MartinPrikryl I am trying scp

Please edit all information into your question + How does the script invoke at ssh invocation? + Post WinSCP log.

"su: must be run from a terminal" – I wonder how exactly does this work with scp. It should fail the same way as with WinSCP. Can you gide us details on that?

@MartinPrikryl I am not sure why I see that error! scp/ssh from command line (linux) works fine!

Added some more debugs, and for sure this is the reason - i.e. su does not allocate a pty when connected via WinScp! When I run via a console based ssh client, I see /dev/pts/N in the logs...

ssh command line has  -T  Disable pseudo-terminal allocation  looks like WinScp is by default doing "no pseudo-terminal alloc" ?

grok'd through the su  sources, and this is the actual check
if ((isatty (0) != 0) && (NULL != caller_tty)) {. In command line ssh case isatty(0) is 1, and callertty: /dev/pts/1; whereas from winscp isatty(0) is 0, and callertty: (null) 

I don't have enough points to start a bounty! But I am really curious about this .. please help!

update: I tried to install a version of su which has the --pty option to create a new pty, but with that also winscp seems to get stuck!

su requires a terminal to function properly, and when used with WinSCP, it does not get the required terminal environment, which leads to errors.
Instead, use sudo instead of su, if possible, consider using sudo with the -i option to switch users. sudo does not require a terminal in the same way su does. Modify your script to use sudo instead of su. For example:
sudo -i -u <anotheruser> <command>

You could also use the script command to create a pseudo-terminal. This allows su to run in an environment where it thinks it has a terminal. Like this:
script -q -c "su - <anotheruser> -c '<command>'" /dev/null

In WinSCP, you can try to tweak the settings to ensure compatibility with the terminal requirements. Go to the Advanced settings in WinSCP and adjust the Shell settings. Set the shell to bash or another compatible shell.
If the above failed, debug it using strace to find what is blocking it.

Thanks. I think I had tried this already, anyway tried it again. This is the error: ! 2024-08-02 18.17.49.305 sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified .. there's something that winscp seems to do differently which is making su not allocate a pty ! i.e, I don't see this line in syslog  : su[14134]: + /dev/pts/0 curruser:otheruser which I see in normal command line ssh case

I added the usage of strace` to my answer. That should show what is failing. If you are allowed to use Linux, that will save you light-years of headaches, ask you SA if you may use it as a subsystem.

I used util-linux's su as that worked!

Nice! So, it did work with su ? It'd be nice to know if I was helpful. Did I answer your question effectively?

yes, it worked with the su I built from util-linux, I am on Debian, which was using shadow su! (I didn't know this distinction before).

That's great! Can the question be marked as answered? That helps to keep the threads short.

Great to hear it worked! Just to clarify, Debian’s default su is from the shadow package, which lacks the --pty option; the util-linux version adds this feature. If you’re satisfied with the solution, please consider marking the issue as resolved. Thanks!
